# Printing from Windows machines to CUPS works erratically

Tags: printing, samba, network-printer, cups

I'm trying to construct a Linux print server to be accessed by Windows machines. The setup is as follows:

- Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop
- CUPS 1.6.1
- Printers shared via Samba 3.6.6
- Windows machines are running Windows 7, Windows XP

Printing from Ubuntu works fine. Installation of the shared printers in Windows also seems to work. However, I'm unable to print arbitrary documents from Windows, though some printing efforts do work. Here's what I observed so far:

- Printing a text file from Notepad on the shared printer doesn't work. No error messages, no document in Windows' printer status window.
- Printing from WordPad doesn't work either.
- Printing from Microsoft Word does work.
- Printing test pages works.
- Opening an image file in MS Paint and trying to print it doesn't work.
- Dragging the same image file onto the printer status window will print the file.

All of these are repeatable. What could be the issue here, preventing arbitrary printing?

Comment: why do you use samba to export the printers? Cups is enough.

Comment: I'm experimenting. Printing over AppSocket works fine already; I would like to know more about Samba, if only for future reference.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I cannot print MSword or Excel etc. Did you find any solutions ? @waldrumpus

Comment: @Arda I'm afraid I haven't; we've abandoned this configuration in favor of using a Windows print server

Comment: @waldrumpus Thanks for the heads-up. The weird thing is that it runs fine while printing from LibreOffice, MS Office or browser directly, but notepad or wordpad doesn't work. The files don't even go to print queue. I'm still digging, I'll let you guys know if I find something useful.